Call read only ink contract functions from subxt
How do i do something like
cargo contract call --contract  --message get --suri //Alice
in subxt or from a rust backend
the docs in subxt focus mostly on signing and submitting txs and events hence wasnt able to really find out how to call read only ink functions

Calling a read or write function should be the same in an ink! contract. Both are a contract message.
EDIT:
So when calling a contract the bare_call function returns the ContractExecReturn type. This is defined by the generic ContractResult type where we are interested in the result field, which is set to ExecReturnValue. Then we need to decode the data field's bytes into the return value returned by the message. You can look at these integration tests for how you can do it (it is calling the following contract message)
Note that we had to decode the bytes [1..] for some reason to get the correct value. I can't explain you how yet unfortunately (see open question)

hi - is there any example of calling a smart contract function using subxt etc - do i need to query the node storage?? the other extrinsic apis are only submitting a tx related
thanks for the reply and would really appreciate a follow up on the same...

Edited my answer, hope it helps

thanks for coming back - that does make a lot of sense was using subxt in this instance and not a substrate node (where i can plugin the contracts pallet and use the bare call method) the decoding is something i was doing (while indexing the chains events)
is there no other way to call a read only method from a rust backend ( without running a node) sorry for the questions hope i am making sense though
